# annotation @WebService must autodeploy the service?

Tags: java, web-services, jbpm

I have read that with the @WebService annotation there is no need of other configuration files (web.xml) to have the Service class discovered and deployed and the webservice online.

Is that true?

In all compliant Java EE servers?

Is the URL for the service standard?

It depends on the attributes of the @WebService annotation?

What is that URL in case of Wildfly? I have tried with http://localhost:8080/MyService but it didnt work. Maybe something like http://localhost:8080/{autoDeployWebServices}/MyService?

Comment: Try this: `http://localhost:8080/yourWebAppName/MyService?wsdl`

Comment: I have tried http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/MyService?wsdl, but it didnt work. Is code that I deployed under kie workbench

Comment: What's the name of the web project where you're deploying this class decorated with `@WebService`?

Comment: Is not really a web proyect. Is a workflow project in jbpm under kie workbench

Comment: Oh ok, then probably your class decorated with `@WebService` is not being interpreted by Wildfly and is just a plain class. I'm not sure of this since I haven't worked with jbpm. I suggest you to provide enough info to replicate your problem in order to get accurate help on your specific problem.